# json encode passes to array, cannot select item, although the array as a whole works

Tags: php, jquery

I use json.encode from php and pass it array in jquery ajax, although `console.log(links);` works , I don't see anything in the console for selecting an item (for example `console.log(links[1]);`

the commented codes are the ones that are not working

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        var links = [];
             $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'slider_pull_data.php',
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, j) {
                        links.push(j.photo);
                    });
                }
            });
        // console.log(links[1]);
        // $('#big_slider').css("background-image", "url(uploads/" + links[0]  + ")");
        console.log(links);
        $(".numbers").hover(function(){
            var imageNumber = Number($(this).text()) - 1;
            $('#big_slider').css("background-image", "url(uploads/" + links[imageNumber]  + ")");
        });
    });
```

Comment: You have to place the not-working parts in the success function otherwise they are executed before the query has returned and links is still `[]`

Comment: @MEE wow, thanks, that really worked! .. you can write it as an answer and I will select it best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place the not-working parts in the success function otherwise they are executed before the query has returned and links is still `[]`.

This would be similiar to this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var links = [];
             $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'slider_pull_data.php',
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, j) {
                        links.push(j.photo);
                    });
                    console.log(links[1]);
                    $('#big_slider').css("background-image", "url(uploads/" + links[0]  + ")");
                }
            });
        console.log(links);
        $(".numbers").hover(function(){
            var imageNumber = Number($(this).text()) - 1;
            $('#big_slider').css("background-image", "url(uploads/" + links[imageNumber]  + ")");
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have another question: why does it work when mouse hovers? it shouldn't work because it's outside the ajax function

Comment: @JohnF. I don't know. I did not changed the hover part, so it should be exactly the code you wrote in the question. If you have a new question please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: no, these codes are working fine. my question is, actually they should not, because the hover triggering outside ajax, I wonder why it works

Comment: @JohnF. The hover is not triggering any AJAX calls. Only a browser request to the image you set.

Comment: oh I understand now.